# Putting a ContentControl *inside* a WPF DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, wpf-controls

I have a custom Expander control called `SpecialExpander`. It is basically just a standard `Expander` with a fancy header and a couple properties (`HeaderText` and `IsMarkedRead`).

I began by creating a simple class:

```
public class SpecialExpander : Expander
{
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarkedRead { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a style that sets a couple properties on the expander (e.g., margins, padding, etc.) and, importantly, it also defines a custom `DataTemplate` for the `HeaderTemplate` property. The template is basically a grid with two rows.

As shown in the illustrations below...

- for the top row, I'd like a fixed layout (it's always `TextBlock` `TextBlock` `CheckBox`)
- for the bottom row, however, I want to be able to provide custom XAML for each expander.

I tried putting `<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" ... />` in the `DataTemplate`, but I couldn't figure out how to hook it up properly.

---

[alt text http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1194/contentcontrolwithintem.jpg](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1194/contentcontrolwithintem.jpg)

---

[image]

---

**Question**

How can I build a `DataTemplate` for my `SpecialExpander` so that the header has some fixed content (top row) and a place-holder for custom content (bottom row)?

For the second illustration, I would want to be able to do something like this:

```
<SpecialExpander HeaderText="<Expander Header Text>" IsMarkedRead="True">
    <SpecialExpander.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton Content="High" />
            <RadioButton Content="Med" />
            <RadioButton Content="Low" />
        </StackPanel>
    <SpecialExpander.Header>
    <Grid>
        <Label>Main Content Goes Here</Label>
    </Grid>
</SpecialExpander>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hit me this morning how to solve this: instead of building a `SpecialExpander`, I just need a normal `Expander`. Then, for the header, I will use a custom `ContentControl` called `SpecialExpanderHeader`.

Here's how it works...

**SpecialExpanderHeader class:**

```
public class SpecialExpanderHeader : ContentControl
{
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarkedRead { get; set; }
}
```

**SpecialExpanderHeader style:**

```
<Style TargetType="custom:SpecialExpanderHeader">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="custom:SpecialExpanderHeader">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=custom:SpecialExpanderHeader}, Path=HeaderText}" />
                        <CheckBox Margin="100,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=custom:SpecialExpanderHeader}, Path=IsMarkedRead}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Separator Grid.Row="1" />
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Expander style**

```
<Style x:Key="Local_ExpanderStyle" TargetType="Expander" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Expander}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
</Style>
```

**Usage**

```
<Expander Style="{StaticResource Local_ExpanderStyle}">
    <Expander.Header>
        <custom:SpecialExpanderHeader IsMarkedRead="True" HeaderText="Test">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <RadioButton Content="High" />
                <RadioButton Content="Medium" />
                <RadioButton Content="Low" />
            </StackPanel>
        </custom:SpecialExpanderHeader>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Grid>
        <!-- main expander content goes here -->
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

Comment: I love it when that happens :)

Comment: Hi if it is Ok to you then, Can you share this whole sample application with us please so that everyone can enjoy the code?