# WPF - Hosting a content control inside a Data Template via code

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to host a content control within a data template.

Exactly similar to this: 
[Putting a ContentControl *inside* a WPF DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099765/putting-a-contentcontrol-inside-a-wpf-datatemplate)

I was successful in doing it via XAML. I'd like to do the same via code.

I created a style :

```
<Style x:Key="radioButtonAddtruefalse">
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <RadioButton Content="True"  IsChecked="{Binding Value}"></RadioButton>
          <RadioButton Content="False" IsChecked="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource _invertedBooleanConverter}}"></RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

and within a data template:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource radioButtonAddtruefalse}"> /ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
```

I tried doing this via code, but found nothing under DataTemplate that allows me to host a contentcontrol. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471405/create-datatemplate-in-code-behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copied from [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/75b9f834-9afa-481b-8f5b-be81a6338d0c) but this should work. Havent tried it though.

```
FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

Binding placeBinding = new Binding();

fef.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, placeBinding);

placeBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Name");

dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();

dataTemplate.VisualTree = fef;
```

Also look at
[Create DataTemplate in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471405/create-datatemplate-in-code-behind)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out the contentcontrol when done in xaml doesn't really appear in the Template's visualtree. It's there as a child... Found a workaround. (Not specific to above discussion, hence not putting it in). I did learn about FrameworkElementFactory though. Thanks.